# Help with putting a list in SQL database!

Tags: sql

I need to add a list into a sql database. Basically, the list needs to be a predefined list of locations that something could be shipped to. Any idea?

Comment: Where's the list coming from?

Comment: Is this to be done all in SQL or are you using .net as well? or some other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

```
CREATE TABLE locations(
  id int auto_increment,
  location varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO locations(location) VALUES('location#1');
...
```

This would work for me...

**Now, if you did notice any sarcasm here, that's because you did no effort on your question.**
- Did you try anything? If yes, what didn't work? Why it didn't work?
- What kind of database are you using?
- What are the required fields of your table?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2...) values ('ABC','XYZ'...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a list or a `List<string>` ?

To add multiple items, from a List, obviously yoou would just:

```
foreach(string item in Items) {
   InsertIntoDataBase(item);
}
```

There's a lot more to it then that of course, but you aren't giving us much to go on.